# How do I make my catch block go back to the try block in my method?

Tags: java

For my java class we will be asking for user input so I decided to create a method that only returns integers values. When I run my main and enter a double it returns a 0 and does not go back the try block to get another value from the user. Isn't it suppose to go back to the try block after an exception is caught?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;


class MyMethods   {


    public static int getInteger()   {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int  integer = 1;


        try   {

          System.out.println("Please enter integer");
          integer = keyboard.nextInt();

       }   
       catch(InputMismatchException e ) {  //if anything besides an integer is entered we will catch here and go back to try block.

          System.out.println("Please enter integer only!");

      } 


     return integer;

   }


}//end class
```

**Below is test**

```
class methodTest  {

    public static void main(String[] args)    {


    int integerTest = MyMethods.getInteger();
    System.out.println(integerTest);//prints 0 if double is entered


    }//end main


}//end class
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option here would be to use a loop to keep prompting the user for input until a valid value is received:

```
public int getInteger() {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Integer value = null;

    while (value == null) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Please enter integer");
            value = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter integer only!");
        }
    }

    return value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. jGrasp was not saving when I tried a loop for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

This may help !!!

```
public int getInteger() {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int iValue = 0;
    boolean bCorrect = false;
    while (!bCorrect) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Please enter integer");
            iValue = keyboard.nextInt();
            bCorrect = true; // you can also use break; to move out of the loop.
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter integer only!");
            continue;
        }
    }
    return iValue ;
}
```